# If a cell contains two words, how would I use the first letter of the first word but use all the letters of the second word?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Cell A1 contains a name e.g. "Joe Public"

B1 needs to output "jpublic"

The best I can do is:

=LOWER(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),1)) which outputs "j"

This make everything lower case takes the first character from the left and removes the spaces between the name, but how do I get the whole of the surname?

*EDIT*

I have achieved my goal, but can it be tidied up at all?

=LOWER(CONCATENATE(LEFT(A2,1),IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",A2,start-pos)),"",RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)−FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","*",LEN(A2)−LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","",occurrence))),start-pos)))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `SEARCH` - to find the index of the space. Take the `RIGHT` of that and `CONCATENATE` with the first character.

```
=LOWER(CONCATENATE(LEFT(A1, 1), RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) - SEARCH(" ",A1))))
```

[image]

Comment: `SEARCHB` is not the "Reverse" of `SEARCH`. See [documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/search-searchb-HP005209249.aspx). In fact, `SEARCHB` can return unwanted results if a character counts as 2 bytes instead of 1. Using `SEARCH` (not case-sensitive) or `FIND` (case-sensitive) will do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this, but it supposes a space between the forename and the surname:

```
=LOWER(LEFT(A1,1) & RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for names with a single or no space,

```
=LOWER(REPLACE(A1,2,IFERROR(FIND(" ",A1)-1,0),""))
```

To guard against more than a single space in the full name (e.g. Hans Christian Anderson) we could SUBSTITUTE() out any additional spaces.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(REPLACE(A3,2,IFERROR(FIND(" ",A3)-1,0),"")), " ", "")
```